# How to prevent some features from being selected on QGIS 3.28

Tags: pyqgis, qgs

How to prevent some features from being selected on QGIS?

I want to avoid the selection of some features at project level. What I tried so far is this: I created a project macro like this:

```
from qgis.core import Qgis, QgsProject

remocoes_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ing_remocoes_a')[0]

def lock_phase():
    fases = ('2')
    remocoes_lyr.selectByExpression(f"\"Fase\" IN {'(' + ', '.join(fases) + ')'}", Qgis.SelectBehavior(3))
    print(f"A(s) fase(s) {', '.join(fases)} já foi/foram concluída(s)!")
```

But QGIS crashes here. What can I do?